# In zsh how to set an alias for `less` to get stderr output?

Tags: zsh, alias

I find that there is a "[global alias](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_8.html)" for zsh. so when I set

```
alias -g L='| less'
```

`command L` will be replaced with `command | less`.

But it seems that it **cannot** work with stderr output when I set

```
alias -g LL= ' 2>&1 | less'
```

which I expected to behave like `command 2>&1 | less` when using `command LL`.

How can I achieve this goal correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
alias -g LL='2>&1 | less'
```

You had an space in alias assignment, causing the alias failed.

Comment: doesn't work either. i tried this before the current alias version.

Comment: Works for me. What is the output of `alias LL`?

Comment: @chepner sorry i made a mistake, you both are correct; i mistakenly added a space for another alias, which override the current alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
alias -g LL='|& less'
```

`|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |`, so basically both versions should work. Perhaps you have aliased earlier `less` itself and now this command means something different?

Comment: Correct, but the change in the body of the alias is irrelevant. The solution is removing the space following the `=`.

Comment: Yes, i finally realized that another alias override this one.

Comment: @chepner My answer was dictated OP claims in the comment http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158776/in-zsh-how-to-set-an-alias-for-less-to-get-stderr-output#comment260136_158778, that `alias -g LL='2>&1 | less'` doesn't work either.

Comment: @HongxuChen Good to hear the problem is solved.